# Setting A Relative Path for a Keystore File

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project and submitted for review by one of my peers. In their previous review, he stated that my `keystore` file needed to be saved in a relative path. I am submitting via `GitHub`. Currently, my `keystore` file is saved in the root directory of my project. Also, in my `build.gradle`, I have the following:

```
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'Udacity'
        keyPassword 'xxxxxxxx'
        storeFile file('/Users/user/Applications/LiveVotingUdacity/livevotingkeystore')
        storePassword 'xxxxxx'
    }
}
```

How do I save to a relative path? I am very confused.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> A relative path is a way to specify the location of a directory relative to another directory.

According to your code, your `keystore` file is located here.

```
/Users/user/Applications/LiveVotingUdacity/livevotingkeystore
```

And `build.gradle` file, which you use to specify `signingConfigs`, is placed inside you `app` folder:

```
/Users/user/Applications/LiveVotingUdacity/app
```

You need somehow specify that `keystore` file is located one folder above in folder tree. There is `..` symbol which literally means 'parent directory'.

So to specify relative path to your `keystore`, you should use the next path

```
storeFile file('../livevotingkeystore')
```

Comment: So I simply need to change my build.gradle to reflect what you listed above? And it will essentially serve as a reference to the reviewer to know where to locate the file, is that strictly the purpose?

Comment: @tccpg288 yes. If you change your code in that way, it will works without any changes, for anyone who will pull it from Github. But now it will works only on your machine :)